# SQL GROUP BY not working when converting smalldatetime to date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I can't seem to get GROUP BY to work when converting a smalldatetime to date. I have the following query:

```
SELECT CAST(XDate AS DATE) as 'TheDate', SUM (TheCount) as count
FROM TheTable
WHERE XDate >= '4/1/2018' AND XDate < '5/1/2018' 
GROUP BY CAST(XDate AS DATE), TheCount
```

This query returns over 300,000 rows. Last I checked, April only had 30 days in it, so I would expect at most to get 30 rows with a sum for each day. It is like SQL is still taking the time portion into consideration. I am not sure what I am missing. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why are you grouping by the aggregate? The code you posted doesn't even parse, never mind run (even if you corrected `as count` -> `as TheCount`). So I don't know how it's returning any rows at all. Also you really should avoid ambiguous formats like `m/d/y` - in some scenarios that will interpreted as January 4th, not the month of April. Safest format for date only is `yyyymmdd` without dashes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `thecount` from the group by and fix the date constants:

```
SELECT CAST(XDate AS DATE) as TheDate, SUM(TheCount) as count
FROM TheTable
WHERE XDate >= '2018-04-01' AND XDate < '2018-05-01'
GROUP BY CAST(XDate AS DATE)
ORDER BY TheDate;
```

I also discourage you from putting single quotes around column aliases.  First, choose identifier names that do not need to be escaped (such as `TheDate`).  Second, only use single quotes for string and date constants.

Comment: Oh wow, I feel a bit dumb now. :) I was totally focused on the wrong issue. Thanks for your help.